# Google Map API: Why we need to set title for Marker object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

It does make sense to me for setting the title for Markers in google map api. It does not show or anything. So what is that for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers:

> The marker's title will appear as a tooltip.
>
> If you do not wish to pass any Marker options in the marker's constructor, instead pass an empty object {} in the last argument of the constructor.

Comment: But it does not show the tooltip when i hover mouse to it

Comment: It should. I'd have to see your page to help troubleshoot further.

Comment: I got it. It is not a bug. It's just I did not make the mouse stay on the mark long enough.  Thank you.